# Stokes-Einstein Relationship to find time taken to diffuse $x$ distance?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, diffusion, navier-stokes

```
A molecule has a diffusion coefficient of 0.5 × 10-9 m2s-1.
Calculate how long it would take on average for the molecule to diffuse 10 µm.
```

So I have the above question, that is all the information we are given. So I assume I need to use the formula:

z^2 = 2Dt

where 
z^2 = mean squared displacement of the particle.

D = diffusion coefficient

t = time

converting to SI units, I have

to get t I have divided the sqrt of z^2 by 2x0.5×10-9

The answer I get is an insane 36.6 days to diffuse a total of 10 micrometers.

What am I doing wrong here? There are no worked examples in my lecture notes to compare to. But this answer is screaming errors.

Comment: The diffusion coefficient is fine (it's typical of molecules in solution) but they're usually given in cm$^2$/s which is probably why @tpg2114 is confused. And your equation is right. You've just done the calculation incorrectly (it's *not* 36 days). Try again. You say something about taking a "sqrt". You shouldn't be square-rooting anything...

Comment: @lemon I was thinking about gasses, didn't even consider that Navier-Stokes was about liquids too. Obvious in hindsight, but didn't think of it up front.

Answer (score 1):

Congratulations on realizing that your answer is "insane". Too many people make a mistake, but "just go with it", because that's what their calculator told them. A sanity check is good and necessary.

If you rearrange your equation, you should get

$$t = \frac{z^2}{2D}$$

Substituting $D=5\times 10^{-10}~\rm{m^2/s}$ and $z=10^{-5}~\rm{m}$ I get a very reasonable 100 ms. I think you just made a mistake in the math.

Comment: I took the square root of z^2. I assumed the 10um was displacement, not mean displacement squared.

Comment: Just look at the units.